# inequality for point on a sphere

Tags: inequality

Question: Let $a,b,c,d$ be positive real numbers which satisfy $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = 1$.

Define $f(a,b,c,d) := \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{c} + \sqrt{d}$.

Show that $$ f(1-a,1-b,1-c,1-d) \geq f(a,b,c,d).$$

Remarks:  This problem appears in "Inequalities" by Cvetkovski (p.250).
Unfortunately, there appears to be a gap in the solution.  Namely, if $a > 1/2$,
then $(1 - 2a) < 0$ and this causes trouble (p.251).
  Nevertheless, is the original inequality itself still valid?

Comment: I have looked through the solution given on pages 250 and 251 but I don't see any part where $1-2a < 0$ would cause trouble. Can you explain why exactly you think this would cause trouble?

Comment: it is here $\sqrt{1-a}-\sqrt{a}=\frac{1-2a}{\sqrt{1+a}+\sqrt{a}}$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: Why would that cause trouble? This would only imply that $\sqrt{1-a} < \sqrt{a}$, which is perfectly fine.

Comment: but it is true if $a>1/2$ or in the other case

Comment: no there is no problem in that point

Comment: See here: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=989256#p989256

Comment: thanks for the reference;  yes, the trouble arises e.g. for a=1 in the third display line on page 251